# Android Development for Dummies

Tags: android, eclipse, avd-manager

My book (Android Development for Dummies)is asking me to set Target in Create New AVD Section to 4.1 but eclipse doesn’t have an option lower than 6.1? Do I have to uninstall eclipse and install a different version?

Comment: Use android studio instead eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your book is kind of out of date. This option tells to Avd Manager which android version should the emulator use,  so there's no problem in target version 6.1, since it offers compatibility with previous versions SDK resources. I strongly recommend that you migrate to start use Android Studio, because it facilitates various tasks and is a more mature tool to interact with Android development SDK and resources.